# set customize attribute value in a sprite in cocos2d ios

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, puzzle, cocos2d-js

I want to make a puzzle game by `cocos2d ios`. For that, I want to set some `customized attribute value` in sprite. Like:

In cocos2d js:***(value, power, picked attribute)***

```
var sprite = cc.Sprite.createWithSpriteFrame("res/dice.png" ,tileImage[0][randomTile]);
            sprite.val = randomTile;
            sprite.power = 0;
            sprite.picked = false;
            sprite.setScale(0.55);
            this.addChild(sprite,1);
            sprite.setPosition(col*tileSize+tileSize/2,row*tileSize+tileSize/2);

tileArray[row][col] = sprite;
```

I want to do this in ***cocos2d ios.*** Can I do this? How?

I can create a sprite in `cocos2d ios` like:

```
CCSprite* ss = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:tileImage[0][randomCandy]];
    ss.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
    ss.scale = 0.55f*appDelegate.deviceScaleFloat*appDelegate.deviceRatinaVariable;
    ss.position = ccp(layer_posX+col*tileSize+tileSize/2,layer_posY+row*tileSize+tileSize/2);
    [self addChild:ss z:1];
```

Also I want to store this sprite in a 2d array, want to access later for finding these ***value, power, picked***

Comment: There's a property called userObject - please use it. In cocos2d-js they had .setUserObject({...}) and .setUserData({...}) for these purposes

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find a solution for this question.

I can do this by `create a sprite object in a cocos touch class.` So, my object class is:

```
The objectSpriteClass.h definition is:

#import "CCSprite.h"

@interface objectSpriteClass : CCSprite
{
    int value;
    int power;
    BOOL picked;

}

@property(readwrite, assign) int value, power;
@property(assign, readwrite) BOOL picked;

- (id)initWithSprite:(int)type;
@end
```

And objectSpriteClass.m class definition is:

```
#import "objectSpriteClass.h"

@implementation objectCandy
@synthesize value, power, picked;
- (id)initWithSprite:(int)type
{
    if( (self=[super init] ))
{
    value = 0; // set value
    power = 1; // set power
    picked = NO; // set
    CCTexture *texture=[CCTexture textureWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"gem-%d.png",type]];
    if( texture ) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
        rect.size = texture.contentSize;
        return [self initWithTexture:texture rect:rect];
    }
}
return self;
}

@end
```

Then you can create an object of this class Like:

```
objectSpriteClass *spriteArray[20];

objectCandy *Obj = [[objectCandy alloc] initWithSprite: 1];

    Obj.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
    Obj.opacity = 1.0f;
    Obj.scale = 1.0f;
    Obj.position = ccp(100, 100);
    [self addChild:Obj z:1];

spriteArray[0] = Obj;
```